# Word for cut-the-knot style solutions

Tags: single-word-requests

I have to solve a Rubik's cube, so I rearrange the stickers.

My friend asks me to remind her to read chapter five, so I immediately say, "Don't forget to read chapter five."

I have to find d such that f(x + d) - f(x) < 0.1, so I pick an infinitesimal d instead of solving the inequality.

I have to untangle something, so I cut the knot.

What do you call a technically correct solution that doesn't answer the question or solve the problem as intended?

(I'm bracing myself now for a bunch of words that meet that description but don't answer my intended question…)

Here's an example sentence:
I wrote a brute-force algorithm, Annette wrote a nondeterministic probabilistic algorithm, Yun wrote a recursive branch-and-bound algorithm, and Jen wrote a(n) ________ algorithm that just returned pre-calculated answers for every possible input.

(It's fine if the words aren't adjectives or don't relate to programming.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to refer to **cutting the knot**, maybe call it a *Gordian solution* to the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to substantiate, better still, support, and strengthen your point to make that qualify as an answer.

Comment: Also, Gordian Knot is an application that calculated the bit rate .... So there's a possibility of  ambiguity, in the domain.

Comment: It's surprising no one here bothered to check what the adjective "Gordian" means and why.

Comment: Unfortunately, people may talk about "cutting the knot" to solve a problem, without knowing the story of Alexander and the knot in Gordium.

Comment: So we know this doesn't work as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Cheating** may be a suitable word.

However there are better *phrases* such as **thinking outside the box**. The general idea is that the problem maker did not intend for this solution to occur.

Answer (score 0):

You might refer to those solutions as *lateral thinking*:

> solving problems through an indirect, creative approach ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_thinking)).

Cutting a difficult knot instead of trying to untie it is a classic "lateral solution".

Answer (score -2):

I think what OP may be looking for here is...

> [**rule of thumb**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rule)
>    *a broadly accurate guide or principle, based on practice rather than theory*

I've just finished reading [David Deutsch's *The Beginning of Infinity*](http://www.amazon.com/David-Deutsch/e/B000APOF56). He constantly distinguishes early cultures adopting *rules of thumb* (methods that *work*, even if the users don't know *why*) from the modern era where Western civilsation is based on *explanations* (and we strive to actually *understand* why some methods work and some don't).